# Ruby on Rails - get file from URL

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm Using Amazon Ads API which giving me a URL as a response... Opening that URL in browser, giving me a file that I need... Problem is I Don't know how to get the file from the URL in ruby... can anyone help me???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
require 'open-uri'
contents = URI.open("https://hello.mdominiak.com").read
```

Documentation:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html